# Invalid argument when trying to bind python socket to IPv6 address

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ipv6

I'm trying from my virtual machine to bind my socket in python to the address of my other virtual machine so that I could sniff the frames that are exchanged by the two. So here's my code

```
    import socket

UDP_IP = "fe80:849b:21f4:624c:d70b"
UDP_PORT = 61627

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data)
```

When I try to execute my python, I get an error message :

```
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
socket.error: [Error 22] Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong, thanks in advance !

Comment: That IPv6 address is not valid.

Comment: why is it not valid?

Comment: Because it doesn't have the mandatory scope ID.

Answer (score 7):

I bet, you had found the answer already, but nevertheless on the first glance I see two issues with your code:

1. In IPv6 fe80::/10 address block is reserved for Link-local addresses. These addresses are valid for local subnet only, therefore they are used with scope suffixes like %eth0 to specify proper scope. Where eth0 is a name of the network interface for which the IPv6 address is valid.

So for my MacOS laptop UDP_IP address could look like:

```
UDP_IP = "fe80:849b:21f4:624c:d70b%en0"
```

2. Next, specifying (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT) tuple is absolutely valid for IPv4 but for IPv6 this tuple should also contain flow_info and scope_id fields. Sometimes, flow_info and scope_id could be omitted or missed: (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT, 0, 0). It may work sometimes, but it's not the right way to use in the code.

So, these fields can be fetched via socket.getaddrinfo(IP, PORT) which returns a list of tuples for each address family and socket_kind. Filter them with something like that:

```
for ainfo in socket.getaddrinfo(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT):
    if ainfo[0].name == 'AF_INET6' and ainfo[1].name == 'SOCK_DGRAM':
        target_address = ainfo[4]
        break

sock.bind(target_address)
```

I'm not sure, if I wrote the sample code right, as I didn't test it, check it before usage.